# Composable Row elements disappear when the font size is set to big

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Currently, I have row with 3 elements, and I want to get something like left side. So far, I'm getting the right one. and my code is like this

```
Row(Arrangement.SpaceBetween) {
    Component1(weight = 1f)
    Component2(weight = 1f)
    Component3(weight = 1f)
}
```

the reason I set `weight = 1f` is that when the font size is set to too big, then it will only show component1 and a bunch of space around it. (com2 and com3 will not show)
thanks so much if anyone can help!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

actually, I think I found the solution, so I create Row for each sub-component, and then set the horizontalArrantment. that fixed my issue